# mysql: only log a certain db or ignore other db's?

Tags: sql, mysql

I'm logging output with

log = /var/log/mysql/query.log

and this works ok, but I only want to log requests to one database and not the others.  How can I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [mysql proxy](http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/MySQL_Proxy) instead.